# shell_exec is blocking until finished, I would like it to be non blocking

Tags: php, linux, terminal

I have the following PHP code:

```
shell_exec("(traceroute odesk.com > trace.txt;echo 'traceIsDone'>>trace.txt) &");
```

This line takes 50 seconds to finish, it worked with ping and when I execute the line in a terminal window it returns immediately:

```
(traceroute odesk.com > trace.txt;echo 'traceIsDone'>>trace.txt) &
```

How can I execute that command and immediately after have PHP go to the next line? So not waiting for the shell_exec command to finish?

Comment: If I use popen instead of shell_exec it doesn't block. I use this in a web page and the user will do several requests to get the total trace. Not sure if popen causes a memory leak as I am ignoring the file handle and never close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `popen()`:

> Opens a pipe to a process executed by forking the command given by command.

It says it forks the command, ie it starts it in a new thread so it doesn't block your main thread. Therefore I think that's what you'd want to use.

You can use it pretty much like `fopen()` (if you're familiar with it), using `fgets()`, `fgetss()` and `fwrite()`.

[popen() in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)